# OmniSharp with Sublime Text does not seem to be running OmniSharpServer

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, omnisharp

I'm trying to get ASP.NET MVC5 projects working within Sublime Text. I've installed both of the OmniSharp and Kulture sublime text plugins.

However, it doesn't appear that the OmniSharp server is running, as I'm not able to get any meaningful auto-complete options. I've followed all of the steps in [this guide](http://omnisharp-sublime.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (except the one about the `.sln` files, as I don't have a `.sln` file, and the documentation states `.proj` files are automatically found).

Also, the Rename/Go To Definition options do not seem to be working at all either. Do I need to somehow start the OmniSharp server with Sublime text at all?

When I install the OmniSharp plugin within Atom (http://atom.io), I have to manually start the OmniSharp plugin (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) and then I get all the functionality as expected.

So, I'm just wondering if there is something glaringly obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm having this very same problem. Debugging the plugin code I found that server_ports variable(omnisharp.py) is None and this is causing the problem.
I'm no Python expert and neither ST3 plugin expert.

If it help I'm running on Fedora 21.

Comment: are you using Windows, Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug into the plugin code and found that the OmniSharpServer only starts when a C# file is opened. See [`server_runner.py`](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-sublime/blob/master/listeners/server_runner.py) in the OmniSharpSublime repository.

I changed the code to test for a solution or `project.json` in the current view. Try this:

```py
import sublime_plugin

from ..lib import helpers
from ..lib import omnisharp


class OmniSharpServerRunnerEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_activated(self, view):
        if helpers.is_csharp(view) or helpers.current_solution_or_project_json_folder(view):
            omnisharp.create_omnisharp_server_subprocess(view)
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, support for Asp.Net5 projects is not packaged.

You can get to work however by cloning the Roslyn branch of omnisharp-sublime (https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-sublime/tree/roslyn) into your sublime plugin folder.